# Does ExoPlayer support HDCP (and how)?

Tags: android, mpeg-dash, exoplayer, hdcp

I've got a working Exoplayer implementation for my Android app, and I need to know if Exoplayer supports playing DASH videos in HDCP (and how exactly does this work). The demo app has Samples which have "HDCP capabilities" but I couldn't find anything in the codebase relating to how it deals with this (Does the DASH manifest file itself specify the HDCP capabilities?).

Answer (score 1):

`ExoPlayer` uses `android.media.MediaCrypto` for decryption. For protected content, `MediaCrypto` will use secure decoders that are capable of engaging HDCP stack (depending on HDCP flags in the license, not the manifest). So license defines if HDCP is required and which version (1, 2, 2,1 or 2.2).